# Less @import (reference) not working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012, less

I have been working with the Less framework recently within visual studio 2013 and MVC5; I have tried to implement the import by reference feature as detailed [here](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options):

I have the following code in a less file that references bootstrap's less file as follows:

```
@import (reference) "../bootstrap/bootstrap.less";

#content {
    > form {
        .form-horizontal;
    }
}
```

From the documentation I expect the styles that apply to `.form-horizontal` to be applied to my `#content > form` selector. However, it looks like all the styles from bootstrap.less are also being imported as styles are outputed which do not appear to have any bearing on a form element, eg:

```
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.3333333;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.btn-group-sm > .btn {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.btn-group-xs > .btn {
  padding: 1px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Also, these styles are included in the output even if I remove all bootstrap class references from my styling.

Is this correct or am I importing the bootstrap references incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of `:extend()` which is widely used in Bootstrap. As noted in http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options-reference:

> `reference` styles will not show up in your generated CSS unless the reference styles are used as mixins or extended.

To get rid of unnecessary styles be more specific:

```
@import "../bootstrap/variables.less";
@import "../bootstrap/mixins.less";
@import (reference) "../bootstrap/forms.less";

#content {
  > form {
    .form-horizontal;
  }
}
```

Comment: A perfectly succinct answer if I have ever seen one, thank you

Comment: Technically you *don't* need `(reference)` with `variables.less` and `mixins.less` imports at all. Neither of these two less files generate any CSS code.

Comment: **Not true**: `mixins.less` will be generated w/o `(reference)`. What about `variables.less` — yes, it is optional.

Comment: @tonystar Did you actually tested this? What Bootstrap version?

Comment: Sure. Works like a charm. v3.3.5.

Comment: No, I was asking about "`mixins.less` will be generated w/o `(reference)`". Yet again `mixins.less` should not generate any CSS with or without `(reference)`.

Comment: @tonystar, I susect you still misunderstand what I'm talking about. I'm not about you code above is wrong, I just remark that `(reference)` option for `mixins.less` there is redundant (and ideally to be avoided as misleading/confusing). As for how Less works, you can be sure [I'm pretty familiar with it](http://lesscss.org/about/#team).

Comment: Your truth. But why do you think `(reference)` is misleading? Yes, it's optional for this exact case. But what if you make a mistake and say forget the parentheses in `mixins.less`? Imho specifying it is much more obvious and clear: "I want this file to be imported, by reference".

Comment: @seven-phases-max finally agreed and updated the answer! Variables and mixins are *those things* which should be imported w/o reference.

Comment: @tonystar I upvoted your answer in its initial state anyway.